# Setting front Page using Storytime Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the [Storytime CMS](https://github.com/CultivateLabs/storytime) Gem for my Rails application. The Gem is great but I haven't found a ton of documentation. After the default installation, the front page is the blog but I need to set this to a specific page (Home) instead. How can I set the root to a page instead of the blog? I've looked through the initializer and through the generated code but didn't see anything that looked like it might be right. I also tried modifying the storytime mount point to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`, Storytime will have inserted a line that looks like:

```
mount Storytime::Engine => "/"
```

You can change the `"/"` to be e.g. `"/blog"`

Then you can use `root` (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) as normal to serve up your own page.

Comment: Thank you so much @gwcodes. I discovered that Storytime installs high_voltage to load static pages. So I set up a static home page, changed the mount point like you suggested and it's working great.